# Error: The stream is invalid or no corresponding signature was found

Tags: c#, stream, sevenzipsharp

I have this code:

```
MemoryStream recChunk = new MemoryStream();
byte[] sizeChunkB = new byte[10];
int sizeChunk;
streamLigacao.Read(sizeChunkB, 0, sizeChunkB.Length);
sizeChunk = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeChunkB, 0);

int timesToEnter = (int)Math.Ceiling(sizeChunk / 1024.0);

for (int i = 0; i < vezesaEntrar; i++) {
    int size = streamLigacao.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length);
    recChunk.Write(RecData, 0, size);
}
recChunk.Position = 0;
MemoryStream deCompressed = new MemoryStream();

using (var tmp = new SevenZipExtractor(recChunk)) {   
    tmp.ExtractFile(0, deCompressed);
}
recChunk.Close();
```

And it is returning this error:

> The stream is invalid or no corresponding signature was found.
>
> STREAMLIGACAO is a networkstream

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what do you want to decompress? I can't see any filename or data in your recChunck

Comment: My variables were not in englis that is why i dide not post the full code. But i have since updated the question.code

Comment: I still can't see what data do you want to extract. What does `streamLigacao`contains?

Comment: Unless you are reading from a file of a known size, you must pay attention to the result returned by `stream.Read`. It may give you fewer bytes than you wanted.

Comment: What do you mean? @Luaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of issues with your code. Most importantly:

- `Read` returns the amount of bytes read. If you ignore that, you're writing more than you've read, causing trouble.
- Streams don't "reset" automatically - `recChunk` is at the end, so anyone reading from it will just exit immediately. You have to do `recChunk.Position = 0;` first.
- `(int)Math.Ceiling(sizeChunk / 1024.0)` may not be accurate enough. You really want to stay with integer mathematics, rather than involving floating points.
- Additionally, it shows that you expect a value that isn't an integer multiple of 1024, and yet you're assuming that you'll read (and write) exactly `RecData.Length * timesToEnter` bytes of data. That's fishy.

It's not clear what data is supposed to be in `recChunk` - I'm assuming it's a valid compressed bytestream understood by the decompression library of your choice.

**EDIT:**

Since your input stream is a TCP stream, all the above is even more important. A better read-write loop would look something like this:

```
var remainingBytes = sizeChunk;
var buffer = new byte[4096];

while (remainingBytes > 0)
{
  var bytesRead = streamLigacao.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  if (bytesRead == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection closed.");

  recChunk.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code. It still does not work. I need to know how many packets is receiving that is why i am using  
(int)Math.Ceiling(sizeChunk / 1024.0)

Comment: @meme So `RecData` is a TCP stream? That just makes all the notes apply double. You're not going to read 1024 bytes at a time from a TCP stream unless you're very lucky. Instead, keep reading until you read enough bytes - a simple `while(bytesLeft > 0)` will do.

Comment: No 'RecData' is a byte array with '1024' in size. 'streamligacao' is a 'networkstream'.

Comment: The problem was on the client side. It was also this '.Position = 0;'. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @meme Glad I could help. But still make sure to replace your `Read`/`Write` loop - the way you're doing it now isn't safe. Let me add a quick sample.

Comment: @meme Oh, and you shouldn't edit your question with "fixes" from the comments and answers - that just invalidates the old answers. As it stands now, your question is also your answer, which kind of misses the point of Q&A :D You should only add (and remove) information based on the comments, not the solution.